# Auto start and loop ins't working for audio attribute

Tags: html, audio

```
            <audio autoplay loop>
                <source src="boss.mp3">
              </audio>
```

This is in my game index, and it should work.  But when i load up the page I hear nothing, all my other sounds work except this one

Here is my full code https://github.com/Mzema4818/Dragon-Escape/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Did you try with a capital B? `Boss.mp3`

Comment: yes I did to do too

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers block autoplay request due to it's annoying feature by default. I have made it to work using the code below. It works on chrome. It also work on safari only if the user allows to play autoplay from site preferences setting. If you are on safari, go to Safari -> Settings for this website -> "Allow all Auto-Play". I hope it helps.

```
<audio class="bgmusic" autoplay loop>
  <source src="boss.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bgmusic').on('canplay', function() {
      this.play();
    });
  });
</script>
```

I had forked your GitHub repository to tweak the scripts. Here's the link to my repo: https://github.com/ashishpatelcs/Dragon-Escape/blob/master/index.html

and a working demo: https://ashishpatelcs.github.io/Dragon-Escape/

Please let me know if there is any issue.